# How to count strings added to a list array using count sub method and a target string in Java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods

```
public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList < String > y = new ArrayList < > ();
        y.add("Go");
        y.add("Home");
        y.add("Go");
        y.add("Home");
        System.out.println(y);
        countOccurence("Go", y);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
    public static int countOccurence(String y, ArrayList < String > t) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= t.size(); i++) {
            if (y.equalsIgnoreCase(t.get(i))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

This code does not allow me to print the count returned by the sub method countOccurence.  this code should count the number of time the target string appears in array Y and then return it to the main so it can be printed. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Your code is crashing with `Index 4 out-of-bounds for length 4`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the occurence:

```
System.out.println("Occurence of 'Go' is " + countOccurence("Go", y));
```

You should also remove change `i <= t.size();` to `i < t.size();` to avoid `IndexOutOfBounds` error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
    y.add("Go");
    y.add("Home");
    y.add("Go");
    y.add("Home");
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println("Occurence of 'Go' is " + countOccurence("Go", y));
}

public static int countOccurence(String y, ArrayList<String> t) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        if (y.equalsIgnoreCase(t.get(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are printing the list not the result of your `countOccurence` method. To fix it -

Store the result of `countOccurence` in a variable

```
int count = countOccurence("Go", y);
```

Print the count in the next line.

```
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: this is all you need!  And maybe the loop condition: `i<=t.size()` cannot work, because any index (of arrays or lists) starts at `0`, so when your list has `4` elements, the index `4` does not exist (index 3 points at the last element since you started counting from 0).

Comment: Yeah I didn’t notice that because the question was about how to print result. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

*Just an optional solution.* In `Java8` , you can do it with `Stream API` to count of occurence  .

```
Map<String, Long> counts =
        listOfString.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

And result code  ;

```
public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList< String > listOfString = new ArrayList < > ();
        listOfString.add("Go");
        listOfString.add("Home");
        listOfString.add("Go");
        listOfString.add("Home");

        Map<String, Long> counts =
                listOfString.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(counts.get("Go"));
        System.out.println(counts.get("Home"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call directly

```
System.out.println(countOccurrence("Go", y));
```

The correct code would be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList < String > y = new ArrayList < > ();
        y.add("Go");
        y.add("Home");
        y.add("Go");
        y.add("Home");
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(countOccurence("Go", y));
    }
    public static int countOccurence(String y, ArrayList < String > t) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
            if (y.equalsIgnoreCase(t.get(i))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to reuse the value, just save it in a variable, like suggested by sneh